# Can't get RwLock to work in multithreaded app

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement `tokio::sync::RwLock` because my app should re-load a configuration file if/when it changes. This involves re-assigning a `Vec` variable with a new one, but there could be many readers at any one time.

There is a struct called `Manifest` that represents a "list" of binaries available for a piece of hardware that I designed. The list is a JSON file which is parsed at startup and whenever it changes.

```rust
use notify::{watcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher};
use semver::Version;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::{fs::File, sync::Arc, thread};
use tokio::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Binary {
    version: Version,
    hardware: Version,
    requires: Version,
    file: String,
}

pub struct Manifest {
    path: String,
    manifest_changed: bool,

    binaries: Arc<RwLock<Vec<Binary>>>,
}

impl Manifest {
    pub fn new(path: String) -> Manifest {
        let bins = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Vec::new()));

        thread::spawn(move || async move {
            let bins = Arc::clone(&bins);
            let (tx, rx) = channel();
            let mut watcher = watcher(tx, Duration::from_secs(10)).unwrap();
            watcher.watch(path, RecursiveMode::NonRecursive).unwrap();

            loop {
                match rx.recv() {
                    Ok(event) => {
                        let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
                        let mut bins = bins.write().await;
                        *bins = serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap();
                    }
                    Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
                }
            }
        });

        Manifest {
            path: path,
            manifest_changed: true,
            binaries: bins,
        }
    }

    pub async fn GetAvailableBinaries(self, hwv: Version, fwv: Version) -> Vec<Binary> {
        self.binaries.read().await.to_vec();
    }
}
```

My issue is that the compiler complains:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely

future created by async block is not `Send`

help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<notify::DebouncedEvent>`rustc
manifest.rs(28, 9): future created by async block is not `Send`
manifest.rs(35, 23): has type `&std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<notify::DebouncedEvent>` which is not `Send`
manifest.rs(38, 40): await occurs here, with `rx` maybe used later
manifest.rs(44, 13): `rx` is later dropped here
mod.rs(617, 8): required by this bound in `std::thread::spawn`
```

I'm not sure I understand why it matters if the channel `Receiver` implements `Send` because it's being created *in* the closure/thread. Further that that reasoning, I really don't know what to look for.

Comment: I'm new to `async`, but it seems to me like the code is lacking something. `async move {...}` is a future. `move || async move {...}` is a closure that returns a future. `thread::spawn` runs the **closure** in another thread, returning the **future** from the `JoinHandle` if you call `join()` on it (which you aren't doing). Nothing in this code actually *polls* the future (causing it to be executed), unless I'm way off base. That seems quite unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I think you want to use `tokio::spawn` instead of `thread::spawn` and just use and `async move` block instead of a closure returning a future.

Comment: This won't work with `tokio::spawn` because the code uses blocking operations (waiting on a channel) inside. The code should either use only async primitives or only synchronous functions. In this case the latter seems more reasonable, because `notify` uses a blocking channel.

Comment: It matters whether it is `Send` because an async function can be moved between threads at every `.await`. In the specific case of configuration files, you should probably use a [`watch`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/sync/watch/index.html) channel rather than an `RwLock`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.